# Populate Spring "property" from Java code

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java class `MySettings` which loads the properties for my application from a JSON file / database / something else.

I have configured `MySettings` to be a bean in the Spring context.

```
<bean id="mySettings" class="com.myapp.MySettings" />
```

I now want to use one of the values in `mySettings` in the spring context file for something that doesn't support SpEL, like the Spring Integration logging channel adapter, e.g.

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logMessageToRemote" 
     logger-name="toRemote" level="#{mySettings.getRemoteLogLevel}"
     expression="payload" />
```

Is there a way I can setup a "property" that can be populated using SpEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from spring docs http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#expressions-beandef

You can also refer to other bean properties by name, for example.

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
   <property name="randomNumber" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>
   <!-- other properties -->
</bean>


<bean id="shapeGuess" class="org.spring.samples.ShapeGuess">
  <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>
   <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

Is this something you are looking for?